# AngularJs send value of a controller to a service

Tags: angularjs, web-services, factory

Question is simple, i have value in a controller, and i want to send this value to another controller.

I have this code :

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.factory("UserService", function() {
  var users = //how to get the value user of MyCtrl ?

  return {
    all: function() {
      return users;
    },
    first: function() {
      return users[0];
    }
  };
});

app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, UserService) {
  var users = ["Peter", "Daniel", "Nina"];
  $scope.users = UserService.all();
});

app.controller("AnotherCtrl", function($scope, UserService) {
  $scope.firstUser = UserService.first();
});
```

I didn't know how to get value of `var users = ["Peter", "Daniel", "Nina"];` from the controller `MyCtrl` in `UserService` ?

live exemple :http://jsbin.com/vacutodo/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

You can inject it into your function:

```
app.factory('UserService', ['MyCtrl', function(MyCtrl) {
    var users = MyCtrl.users;
    ...
};

app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, UserService) {
    var users = ["Peter", "Daniel", "Nina"];
    $scope.users = UserService.all();

    return {
        users: users
    };
});
```